# WebSocket closing immediately using Watson Speech-to-text JS SDK

Tags: speech-to-text, ibm-watson

Trying to use this code from a provided demo, using the latest watson-speech.js from https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/speech-javascript-sdk:

```
document.querySelector('#button').onclick = function () {

  fetch('myserverurl/api/token')
  .then(function(response) {
      return response.text();
  }).then(function (token) {

    var stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({
        token: token,
        outputElement: '#output' // CSS selector or DOM Element
    });

    stream.on('error', function(err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    document.querySelector('#stop').onclick = function() {
      stream.stop();
    };

  }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
  });
};
```

Getting this error immediately upon trying to start the connection in the Chrome console:
WebSocket is already in CLOSING or CLOSED state.

Using Chrome and testing locally.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a scoping error. You are declaring `var stream` inside the `then`, which means that as soon as the `then` complete `stream` no longer exists, and will have been automatically cleaned up.

Add `var stream = null` or `let stream = null` at a higher scope level. You can still initialise it inside your `then` block as

```
}).then(function (token) {
  stream = WatsonSpeech.SpeechToText.recognizeMicrophone({
          token: token,
          outputElement: '#output' // CSS selector or DOM Element
  });
  ...
```

Comment: Tried this, unfortunately it didn't work. For some reason, this code works [here](https://watson-speech.mybluemix.net/microphone-streaming.html) but doesn't work for me.